# Swift Package Manager: Update selection of 'Package Product' retroactivly?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode11, swift-package-manager

Using Xcode 11 beta 6, in a SwiftUI app project, using Swift Package Manager (SPM), how can I change my choice of 'Package Product', **without deleting the package and re-adding it? Is it possible**

[image]

I included the package [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/tree/xcode11), which has SPM support. After having confirmed the git branch `xcode11`, SPM/Xcode finds that Kingfisher contains two 'Package Product', at first I chose only the first, but not 'KingfisherSwiftUI'. Then I realized that I needed that too.

I search for any way of prompting for this dialog again but found none. So instead I deleted the package and re-added it. And there seemed to be no cache, Xcode had to download and build the project again which took some time.

Comment: This is just unbelievable... Still no way to update selection it seems.

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can. Select a target in Targets list and in the General group scroll down until you see Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content.  There you can add/remove libraries for added packages.